# why does not showing my custom post category list in any template?

Tags: templates

i want the category list to be show in any template but does not showing 
code is here what i am using .
can please guide me.
no any result i am getting.
if you have any idea please guide.

|custom post code|

```
<?php 
function themes_taxonomy() {  
    register_taxonomy(  
        'doctorcategory',  //The name of the taxonomy. Name should be in slug form (must not contain capital letters or spaces). 
        'doctors',        //post type name
        array(  
            'hierarchical' => true,  
            'label' => 'Doctors category',  //Display name
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'doctors', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
                'with_front' => false // Don't display the category base before 
            )
        )  
    );  
}  
add_action( 'init', 'themes_taxonomy');

add_action ('init', 'register_Doctors_posttype');
function register_Doctors_posttype() {
  register_post_type( 'doctors',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'doctors' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'doctors Posts' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Add New doctors Post' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New doctors Post' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit doctors Post' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'Add New doctors Post' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View doctors Post' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search doctors Post' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'No doctors post found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No doctors post found in trash' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
      'capability_type' => 'post',
      'rewrite' => array("slug" => "doctors"), // Permalinks format
      'menu_position' => 4,
      'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-portfolio',
      'taxonomies'   => array( 'doctorcategory','mydoctor' ),
      'has_archive' => true,
    )
  );
}


$tax_post_args = get_terms('doctorcategory');
print_r($tax_post_qry);
```

Comment: It should be `print_r($tax_post_args)`. Also, did you assign any post types to the category terms, or are they all empty?

Comment: all are empty...any idea for new code building to get list of category for custom post type?

Comment: If they are all empty, you need to consider the `hide_empty` parameter of `get_terms`, which defaults to `true`.

Comment: Thanks for the guide 
it code doesn't working for me 
but i get one solution for that which is solving my issues 
this is code here 
$args = array('post_type' => 'name', 'taxonomy' => 'taxonamy_name'); $categories = get_categories($args);

Comment: so i just closing this topics and thank you very much..at least you spend the time for me to guide.